# How to get data for user and append in dict as key and value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get data form user (their name as keys and mark as value).

My problem is that how can I get data form user through `Input()` and then select student who got < 33 and print their result

I have tried this method but how can I data form user and store in a dictionary.

```
students = {
    input('Enter name 1: '): float(input('Enter value 1: ')),
    input('Enter name 2: '): float(input('Enter value 2: ')),
    input('Enter name 3: '): float(input('Enter value 3: ')),
    input('Enter name 4: '): float(input('Enter value 4: ')),
    input('Enter name 5: '): float(input('Enter value 5: ')),
   }

# I know this is ugly method to write type() many times, so this is the problem 

print(len(students))
for (name, value) in students.items():
    print(name, sep='\n')
    print(value)

print(*[student for student in students if students[student] < 33], 
  sep='\n')
```

First user will write how many student have, for example `5`

I want to get data form user name and marks like this:

```
   5
   dino
   23.3
   jackson
   33.5
   timcey
   44.5
   james
   55.5
   gardner
   31.2
```

Then calculate who students got less then 36 marks and print their name

```
dino
jackson
gardner
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: if you're looking for a one-liner for your first print try `print("\n".join([f"{student}\n{score}" for student, score in students.items()]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
students = {}
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    students.update({input('Enter name %s: ' % (i + 1)): float(input('Enter value %s: ' % (i + 1)))})

for name, value in students.items():
    print(name)
    print(value)
print(*[student for student in students if students[student] < 33], sep='\n')
```

Example output:

```
5
Enter name 1: dino
Enter value 1: 23.3
Enter name 2: jackson
Enter value 2: 33.5
Enter name 3: timcey
Enter value 3: 44.5
Enter name 4: james
Enter value 4: 55.5
Enter name 5: gardner
Enter value 5: 31.2
dino
23.3
jackson
33.5
timcey
44.5
james
55.5
gardner
31.2
dino
gardner
```

Comment: **could you please explain....**                                                                           `students = {}
  n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    students.update({input('Enter name %s: ' % (i + 1)): float(input('Enter value %s: ' % (i + 1)))})`

Answer (score 0):

To print students who have a score < 36 use a for loop:

```
for student,score in students.items():
    if score < 36:
        print(student)
```